# Java code to compare excel sheets does not work for larger files

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, maven, apache-poi

I have recently done a project in java to compare excel sheets in 2 different folders and generates the result in a summary folder created in the source folder directories. All the code was working fine except for files which have more than 10000 rows. its just creating an empty sheet instead of compared mismatches for larger files. here is the code i used Please help me out.

```
    package com.validation.comparators;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    import org.bson.Document;
    /**
      * The utility class SheetComparator
   */
    public class SheetComparator {
    private SheetComparator() {
    // The utility class
}

/**
 * Compares the document equivalent of two sheets
 * 
 * @param document1
 *            The document 1
 * @param document2
 *            The document 2
 * @return The compared output
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Document compare(Document document1, Document document2) {

    List<String> headers = (List<String>) document1.get("headers");
    List<Document> sheet1Rows = (List<Document>) document1.get("data");
    List<Document> sheet2Rows = (List<Document>) document2.get("data");
    List<Document> temp;
    List<Document> comparedOutput = new ArrayList<>();

    if (sheet1Rows.size() < sheet2Rows.size()) {
        temp = sheet1Rows;
        sheet1Rows = sheet2Rows;
        sheet2Rows = temp;
    }

    int length = sheet1Rows.size();
    int length2 = sheet2Rows.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
        Document sheet1Row = sheet1Rows.get(i);
        Document sheet2Row = sheet2Rows.get(i);
        Document comparedRow = new Document("row number",
                new Document("value", sheet1Row.getString("row number")).append("color", "WHITE"));
        Boolean completeMatch = true;

        for (String header : headers) {
            Boolean isNull = false;
            String value1 = sheet1Row.getString(header).trim();
            String value2 = sheet2Row.getString(header).trim();

            if (StringUtils.isAnyBlank(value1, value2)) {
                completeMatch = false;
                isNull = true;
            } else if (!StringUtils.equals(value1, value2)) {
                completeMatch = false;
            }

            if (isNull) {
                comparedRow.append(header, new Document("value", StringUtils.isBlank(value1) ? value2 : value1)
                        .append("color", "RED"));
            } else {
                comparedRow.append(header, new Document("value", value1).append("color", "WHITE"));
            }
        }

        if (!completeMatch) {
            comparedOutput.add(comparedRow);
        }
    }

    for (int i = length2; i < length; i++) {
        Document row = sheet1Rows.get(i);
        Document comparedRow = new Document();

        for (String header : headers) {
            String value = row.getString(header);
            comparedRow.put(header, new Document("value", value).append("color", "RED"));
        }

        comparedRow.append("row number",
                new Document("value", row.getString("row number")).append("color", "WHITE"));
        comparedOutput.add(comparedRow);
    }

    headers.add(0, "row number");
    return new Document("data", comparedOutput).append("headers", headers);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Which version of POI are you useing?

Comment: I don't see any usage of `apache poi` in that code. Where do you think you are using `apache poi`?

Comment: I am not getting any errors its comparing the sheets but instead of printing mismatches its just creating an empty xlsx file in summary folder I am not using POI now i wanted to know if using POI was the solution to compare more than 100000 records

Answer (score 0):

Try it, set the jvm's (java's) memory high. The problem is you have to read the entire DOM object hierarchy.

*Otherwise* you need ony to sequentially read the documents, by sheet, by row, by cell.
So instead of having some DOM object in memory, you could:

- Write a sequential stream (as text document) of the documents to a file.
- Convert both Excels to text.
- Read two streams and make a diff for every token.
- Probably you can immediately write an diff report.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks, never used SXSSFWorkbook. I knew it came after the DOM versions, and started for writing. But that was years ago. I will remove that part.